# Scanning columns and comparing values?

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing

**I'm trying to create a formula that does the following:**

If a nonzero value is present in Column A, search Column B until a nonzero value is present. If Column B's corresponding Column C value is greater than Column B's corresponding Column D value, print Column B's Column C value, else print Column B's Column D value. (Print nothing if a zero value is present in Column A)

**Here's what I have right now:**

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(INDEX(B2:C11,MATCH(TRUE,B2:B11,0),2)>VLOOKUP(INDEX(B2:C11,MATCH(TRUE,B2:B11,0),2),C2:D11,2),INDEX(B2:C11,MATCH(TRUE,B2:B11,0),2),VLOOKUP(INDEX(B2:C11,MATCH(TRUE,B2:B11,0),2),C2:D11,2)),"")
```

**Here's what it looks like:**

[image]

Comment: I've uploaded an image with expected returned values included. Hope this helps to clarify.

Comment: My apologies, it should have been 10. I've now changed the values around to illustrate the case in which the Column D value is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be of some use to you:

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()-2+MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B2:B1000)<>"",0,0),0)+1)="","",MAX(INDIRECT("C"&ROW()-2+MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B2:B1000)<>"",0,0),0)+1&":D"&MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B$2:B1000)<>"",0,0),0)+11))),"")
```

Comment: No worries, I went back and tweaked the formula until it worked as needed. The real key was realizing the need to use Indirect(), which I didn't consider.